# Cucumber makes @browser=nil in After hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I want to keep browser open for several scenarios, but from After hook method `rb_language.rb/end_scenario` where `@current_world=nil` and `@browser` is a part on `@current_world` object.

So even if I don't call `@browser.close` in After hook, `@browser` object is `nil` and I can't use it anymore while browser window is still open.

Is there any way to use opened browser window for several scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly I defined a variable called browser (not @browser) in my hooks file, outside of any cucumber hooks, that created my browser instance and then assigned the instance variable @browser to point to it in my before hook, i.e. @browser = browser.  I then handled the teardown of both in my at_exit hook.

If that doesn't make sense or doesn't work, could you please post your hooks file (or an edited version of it)?